# Arch Linux and secure boot issues

Tags: arch-linux, secure-boot

I want to install arch linux on my laptop, but I want to be able to play my games that require secure boot on windows 10. I found a tutorial to make it secure boot compatible:

Flash the ISO on the usb stick as you would normally do.

Then:

1. navigate to ~\EFI\boot\
2. rename BOOTx64.EFI as loader.efi
3. download signed shim.efi in the same folder
4. rename it as BOOTx64.EFI
5. boot the thing and enroll from disk the ~\EFI\boot\loader.efi hash

I have no idea what number 5 means. What does "enroll from disk the ~\EFI\boot\loader.efi hash" mean? My windows depends on this.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the signed shim, you'll also need its companion MokManager program, `mmx64.efi` to be present in the same directory as the shim-named-as-`BOOTx64.efi`.

Now, when the shim finds nothing it can boot, it shoud automatically start `mmx64.efi`, which should display a white-on-blue screen titled something like `Shim UEFI key management`. It might display a verification failure message first, which you will need to acknowledge by pressing Enter.

Then it will display a menu that should include at least three items:

- Continue boot
- Enroll key from disk
- Enroll hash from disk

(If you had previously tried to use `mokutil` to create and enroll a Machine Owner's Key, it would also display an `Enroll MOK` option, but that's not what you are asking.)

When you select `Enroll hash from disk`, it will first ask you to select a partition, and then to navigate into the directory that contains the `.efi` file which you want whitelisted by Secure Boot. You should navigate to your `\EFI\boot\loader.efi` and select it. It will allow you to inspect the hash before enrolling it, and then ask for a final confirmation before the enrolling is completed.

This webpage has the hash enrollment procedure with screenshots, although for a different `.efi` file: https://www.aioboot.com/en/secure-boot/

You might then have to rename your `loader.efi` as `grubx64.efi`, as `grubx64.efi` is the default filename most versions of the shim expect to use to continue booting.

I'm not certain, but you might have to enroll the kernel file on the USB in the same way too.

Anyway, that should allow you to start the Arch installation process in a Secure Boot-compatible way. Note that you will also need to take Secure Boot-specific steps when setting up a bootloader for your installed Arch - [the Arch Wiki has more information on this.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface/Secure_Boot)

I'm curious to know which games *require* Secure Boot, as personally I don't seem to have encountered any of those yet. I'm guessing they might be some multiplayer games that have to be extra paranoid about cheating.

Comment: To answer your question about which games require secure boot, Valorant as of recent now requires secure boot to be enabled for vanguard to trust your system. It's the reason I'm here, and I'm assuming same goes for OP.

Comment: Valorant is the only thing keeping windows on my pc lol!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)